# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in SQL when creating a column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL, using SSMS SQL 18.12. I've been searching and know how to convert `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd-mm-yyyy` using `SELECT`. Just wonder whether there is a way to store this format from the start.

```
CREATE TABLE BILL
(
    BILLCODE NVARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    ORDERDATE DATE,
    CUSTOMERCODE NVARCHAR(5) 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERCODE),
    TOTAL MONEY
)

INSERT INTO BILL 
VALUES ('HD001','20220601','KH01',82000),
```

Result is `2022-06-01` in the `ORDERTIME` column. But I need `01-06-2022`. And I also need `01/06/2022` format.

**PS**: I managed to display it with

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '-', '/') AS TIME FROM BILL
```

Thank you!

Comment: What RDBMS? That will directly impact the answer.  Additionally, do you want to actually **store** data in these different format, or **present** it in different formats?

Comment: A *date* column knows nothing about how the data is formatted, it's a binary value, formatting for display is up to you when you query the data. Aside - having a column named *TIME* that is not a time is a little confusing.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase, MySQL, etc.

Comment: @Andrew I found out how to present data in the format I wanted. I just wonder that is there a way to store data in format I asked from the start, when creating that column. Thank you!

Comment: @Stu thank you for your info, I'll edit the column name.

Comment: @TheImpaler ah, I'm using SSMS SQL 18.12, I've edited my question.

Comment: @bandaisme you are free to choose any name you wish, I was simply point out the obvious.

Comment: @bandaisme Please do not fall into [this bad habbit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @TheImpaler I've changed the name in my table and added varchar length, bad habits omitted. Thank you!

Comment: And I personally find it a horribly bad choice to call a column `TIME` that has the datatype `DATE` and quite clearly stores a **date** - not anything with **TIME** ..... Furthermore `TIME` also is a **reserved T-SQL keyword** and should be avoided as column name whenever possible - use a more meaningful name - like `HireDate`,  `Birthdate` or something that clearly says **what** kind of date this column stores....

Comment: @bandaisme I still don't understand clearly why do you need multiple formats. The database stores the date in a unique internal format that is not relevant. With this, I would strongly suggest you manage all dates in the UI and external apps in a single normalized format. This has nothing to do with the database itself.

Comment: @TheImpaler ah I understand now. If I need different formats for different usages, I should handle outside rather than changing the database's original format. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know sql server saves date as binary so you don't need to convert it when you make the column you can just convert it when you select the data

To do it you can use this as the query
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as date